# HTML5 Canvas Example Screenshots

Tags: javascript, html, dom, canvas, html5-canvas

I have come across [html2canvas](http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) thanks to a previous question of mine.  What I am confused about is how could I implement it to do the following:

1. Create a live thumbnail of a live website.
2. When the live thumbnail is clicked it loads a bigger image of the website.
3. What would be the best way to feed the uri's into the script?

All images will have specific hxw set in the image tag or the css for the specific class.

Comment: What have you tried? What kind of problems have you run into? Did you check their API for getting a screenshot, you can probably specify an image size?

Comment: @JuanMendes I have not tried anything yet.  I am after a starting example of how to do it as I find the documentation minimal and the examples very confusing and the use of DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the website you are trying to create a thumbnail for is different from the actual page the user is on, you'll need to first download the HTML of the page to your server (same origin), after which you can wrap it inside an `iframe` and create a screenshot of that.

The screenshot generated will be 1:1 size with the actual site, so to create a thumbnail you'd have to resize the screenshot.

The script doesn't accept HTML, url's or anything else except for DOM elements as an input for rendering a page. As such, the only way you can generate a screenshot using the script is to have it either load on the page where you want the screenshot to be generated or load the page within an iframe (under same origin, so you'll need to download the source through a proxy if you use cross-origin).